# Distributing an iPhone app via VPP

Tags: iphone, software-distribution

We have developed an iPhone app which allows a user offline access to content created via a system we sell.  We are now running into issues getting this approved by Apple, due to the type of app we have been told we have to distribute it via the volume purchase program (VPP).  This is great apart from the major limitations with the program:

1. Some of our clients are not registered with DUNs or the VPP, and the internal processes within that our clients have in place prevent them from registering.
2. Some of our clients are based in countries that can't register for the program.
3. We also want access to the app but can't without using a different method.
4. The distribution process to the different devices appears to be very involved, issuing individual URLs to each user of the system.

Has anyone found a way around these limitations or has any suggestions?

Thanks

Neil